NextsJS hydration error when hot-reloading project with MapLibre map
Newbie here.
I have a project where a small static map is rendered using MapLibre (with react-maplibre) and OpenFreeMaps.
The project loads just fine, but whenever I write some code, save and the project is hot-reloaded, I'm hit with this:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_loaded')
    at Maplibre._updateStyleComponents (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_b38bb3._.js:636:23)
    at Maplibre.setProps (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_b38bb3._.js:401:14)
    at _Map.useIsomorphicLayoutEffect (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_b38bb3._.js:918:29)

Reloading the site in the browser solves the issue most of the time, but sometimes I get an hydration error, which, once again, is solved by reloading the site.
I tried forcing the map component to be rendered at the user, but without success. Any guides?
Code:
import { Card } from '@material-tailwind/react';
import axios from "axios";
import { Map, Marker } from '@vis.gl/react-maplibre';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Clock from "react-live-clock";

export default function LocationMap() {
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState(null);
    const apiKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEATHER_API_KEY;
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchWeather = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(
                    `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apiKey}&q=Tucuman&lang=es`
                );
                const data = response.data;
                setWeather({
                    temp: Math.round(data.current.temp_c),
                    condition: data.current.condition.text,
                    icon: data.current.condition.icon,
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error al obtener los datos meteorológicos:", error);
            }
        };

        fetchWeather();
        const intervalId = setInterval(fetchWeather, 600000);
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, [apiKey]);

    return (
        <Card className="col-span-1 overflow-hidden card w-[250px] h-[250px] relative">
            <Map
                initialViewState={{
                    longitude: -65.2038,
                    latitude: -26.8303,
                    zoom: 8,
                    interactive: false
                }}
                mapStyle="https://tiles.openfreemap.org/styles/bright"
                style={{ width: '250px', height: '250px' }}
                attributionControl={false}
            >
                <Marker longitude={-65.2038} latitude={-26.8303} pitchAlignment="map"></Marker>
            </Map>
            {weather && (
                <div className="absolute bottom-2 right-[7px] bg-white/80 text-gray-800 px-1.5 py-1 rounded-full text-xs flex items-center shadow-md">
                    <div className='flex justify-center items-center w-9 !my-0 leading-none'>
                        <Clock noSsr={false} format={'hh:mm'} ticking={true} timezone="America/Rosario" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='!m-0'>
                        <img src={weather.icon} alt={weather.condition} className="w-7 h-7" />
                    </div>
                    <div className='flex justify-center items-center w-9 !my-0 !mx-0 leading-none'>
                        <span>{weather.temp}°C</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </Card>
    );
}

I tried known solutions to force the react components to render at the user and not the server. But it didn't solve the issue
